# relation between simulator SUMO and Matlab via Traci4Matlab

Tags: simulation

I am new sumo user.

I am trying to tutorials (inter_palmas) for SUMO 0.26 in Windows (7 32 bit) and Traci4matlab (2015).

The status message shows in SUMO: Loading configuration..done , Starting server on port 8813 and doesn't proceed.

Even though I work for a week, I could not find a solution.

Thanks,

Comment: sumo is acting as a server here, waiting for the Matlab client to connect. What did you do on the Matlab side and which messages did it show?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in the recent traci4matlab source code they have changed the default port from 8813 to 8873. I changed my port in the .sumocfg file and now it works as intended.